# Make command can't access awscli

Tags: python, xcode, makefile, aws-cli

I have a Makefile (below) that runs a simple awscli command (the command below is just an example and is not really what I'm using). However, whenever I run the make command, I get the error `make: aws: No such file or directory`. So I just end up copying the aws command and running it directly.

Since I have no issues running aws commands directly, I'm thinking this has something to do with make not having "access" to the awscli, so I checked the installation location of make and awscli.

```
which make -> /usr/bin
pip show awscli -> ~Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages
echo $PATH -> /usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:~/Library/Python/3.7:....
```

Makefile

```
.PHONY: list

list:
  aws s3 ls
```

I'm sure I'm missing something dumb, but I can't figure it out, so I'd love some help / hints at what the issue could be.

Thanks in advance,
Walker

Comment: Are you saying that *the exact same command* that appears in your makefile recipe for target `list` fails when run via `make`, but succeeds when run directly at the command line in the same terminal window from which you run `make`?  That would probably indicate something strange about your shell environment configuration.  Have you exported the `PATH` and any environment variables required by `aws`?

Comment: Maybe try putting `SHELL := /bin/bash` (or analogous) in the first line of the makefile to see if it is a difference in configuration between your shell and `sh` which make is using as default environment to execute recipe lines.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, as an update I installed the awscli with brew and things seem to be working now.  Interestingly, when I ran pip uninstall awscli I got a message saying there was no package awscli.

However, if anyone has any ideas on why I was having the issues described above I'd love to know what was going on.